# Mock an Autowired ExecutorService

Tags: spring, unit-testing, mockito, executorservice

**Abstract:**

I have a Spring `@Component` that uses an autowired ExecutorService as a work pool. I'm using JUnit and Mockito to test the functionality of the component and I need to mock that Executor Service. This has been trivial for other autowired members - a generic helper, and a DAO layer for instance are easily mocked, but I need a *real* Executor Service.

**Code:**

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MadeUpClassNameTest{

  @Mock
  private ExecutorService executor;

  @Before
  public void initExecutor() throws Exception{
      executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
  }

  @InjectMocks
  private ASDF componentBeingAutowired;
...
```

This alone doesn't work, the results of `invokeAll()` is always an empty list.

Attempting to more explicitly mock the executor method also doesn't work...

```
@Test
public void myTestMethod(){
    when(executor.invokeAll(anyCollection()))
        .thenCallRealMethod();
    ...
}
```

I get the cryptically worded exception:

> You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.

(I thought this was a stubbing ?)

I *could* provide a `thenReturn(Answer<>)` method, but I'd like to make sure that the code actually works with an executor, a fair bit of the code is devoted to mapping the results of Futures.

**Problem**
How do I provide a real (or functionally usable mock) Executor Service ? Alternatively, is my difficulty in testing this component a sign that this is a poor design in need of refactoring, or possibly a bad test scenario ?

**Notes**
I want to stress that my problem is NOT getting Mockito or Junit set up. Other mocks and tests work correctly. My problem is specific only to the particular mock above.

**Using**: Junit 4.12, Mockito 1.10.19, Hamcrest 1.3

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the following code runs after the Mock is injected.

```
@Before
public void initExecutor() throws Exception{
  executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
}
```

This causes your local copy of `executor` to be set, but not the one that is injected.

I would recommend using [constructor injection](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-constructor-injection) in on your `componentBeingAutowired` and create a new one in your unit test and exclude Spring dependencies. Your test could then look like something below:

```
public class MadeUpClassNameTest {
    private ExecutorService executor;

    @Before
    public void initExecutor() throws Exception {
        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        ASDF componentBeingTested = new ASDF(executor);
        ... do tests
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use `ReflectionTestUtils` to inject the executor

```
@Before
public void initExecutor() {
  ReflectionTestUtils.setField(componentBeingAutowired, "executor", Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the @Spy annotation.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MadeUpClassNameTest{

    @Spy
    private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    ....

}
```

Comment: In such case I'm getting
`org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Unable to initialize @Spy annotated field 'someField'.
Mockito cannot mock this class: class java.util.concurrent.Executors$FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService.
Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.
If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.

Underlying exception : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error invoking java.lang.ClassLoader#findClass`

Comment: Spy gives an error about an atomic integer being null in the executor

Answer (score -1):

You can use the @Spy annotation.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MadeUpClassNameTest{
@Spy
private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

@Test
...
}
```